# Python can't read txt file that contain "\"

Tags: python

Here is my code that simply just read a txt file as a list:

```
with open('test.txt, 'r') as f:
  account_list = f.readlines()
  f.close()
```

and here is the sample of `test.txt`

```
...
teosjis232:23123/2!@
fdios2313:43242///2323@
...
```

When I run this code to read this txt file, it shows Unicode error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError:'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1632: character maps to <undefined>
```

I think the problem should be `\` in txt file. Anyone can  tell me how to read a txt file that contain a lot of `\`?

Comment: Works for me. Try with `encoding='utf-8'` in `open()`. And you shouldn't close the file when using `with`.

Comment: As a side note, since you are using `with`, you don't need `f.close()`

Comment: Your error message shows that error is at position 1632 is your sample `test.txt` contians position 1632?

Comment: @Guy Thanks for your help but it not work still, it shows another error: "utf-8 codec error, invalid start byte.

Comment: This code works for me also. If you are having issues when converting to strings, you could try using raw strings. Raw strings support "\" characters.

This is a good resource for raw strings: https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string

Comment: You can also just use `bytes` and avoid all encoding problems. You just need to code all subsequent operations according to bytes. `'r'` becomes `'rb'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using utf8 encoding

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  account_list = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried but it show another error: "utf-8 codec error, invalid start byte"

Answer (score 1):

Problem sovled.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='unicode_escape') as f:
  account_list = f.readlines()
```

encoding type `unicode_escape` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text).

```py
import pathlib

with pathlib.Path('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.read_text()
```